# Coin change recursive implementation memoizing wrong values. Could someone help debug?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, memoization, coin-change

Could someone help me figure out why this version of the memoized coin change doesn't work?
**This is to determine the minimum number of coins to make change for a target amount**.
I realize that the cache is putting in the wrong values and without using the memo cache this gives the right answer. I was also able to get a memoized version to work by not passing in the `currNumCoins` as an argument to the recursive calls. I'm just stumped to why this version doesn't work.
I'm initializing `memo` as `Map<Integer, Integer> memo = new HashMap<>()`;

Example input: coins = [1,2,5], targetAmount = 11
Expected Answer : 3
Actual Answer: 7

```
class Solution {    
Map<Integer, Integer> memo = new HashMap<>();

public int coinChange(int[] coins, int amount) {
    return coinChangeRecHelper(coins, amount, amount, 0);
}

public int coinChangeRecHelper(int[] coins, int amount, int currAmount, int currNumCoins) {
    if (currAmount < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    
    if (currAmount == 0) {
        //return 0;
        return currNumCoins;
    }
    
    if (memo.containsKey(currAmount)) {
        return memo.get(currAmount);
    }
    
    int minCoins = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < coins.length; i++) {
        int currCoin = coins[i];
        int numCoinsTmp = coinChangeRecHelper(coins, amount, currAmount - currCoin, currNumCoins + 1);
        if (numCoinsTmp != -1) {
            minCoins = Math.min(minCoins, numCoinsTmp);
        }
    }
    if (minCoins == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        minCoins = -1;
    }

    memo.put(currAmount, minCoins);
    return minCoins;
}
```

}

Comment: Please [edit] and add a programming-language tag and the definition of `memo`. Test data and expected result could also help.

Comment: Updated. Thank you for the suggestions!

Comment: Emm. What 3 combinations you count as valid for sum 11? I see at least 12 variants (551 5222 52211 521111 5111111 222221 2222111...111111111111)

Comment: A memo table maps tuples of arguments to a previously computed return value for those arguments. It looks like you're only mapping a single parameter, when two vary across calls.  This breaks the algorithm, even if it's otherwise correct (which I'm not saying is true).

Comment: Sorry that's my bad. I did not state the problem correctly. I updated the question. Its to find the minimum number of coins to make a target amount. So in the example it would be the 551.

Comment: `if (memo.containsKeymemo.put(currAmount, minCoins);`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a separate `memo` for each recursion so one does not change the other.
For example memorizing which coins where used can be achieved like so:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Solution {

    private Map<Integer, Integer> memo;

    public int coinChange(int[] coins, int amount) {
        memo = new HashMap<>();
        return coinChangeRecHelper(coins, amount, amount, 0, new HashMap<Integer,Integer>());
    }

    public int coinChangeRecHelper(int[] coins, int amount, int currAmount, int currNumCoins, Map<Integer, Integer> coinQty ) {

        if (currAmount < 0) return -1;

        if (currAmount == 0) {
            memo = coinQty;
            return currNumCoins;
        }

        int minCoins = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int currCoin : coins) {
            Map<Integer, Integer> coinQtyCopy = new HashMap<>(coinQty);
            coinQtyCopy.putIfAbsent(currCoin, 0);
            coinQtyCopy.put(currCoin, coinQtyCopy.get(currCoin)+1);
            int numCoinsTmp = coinChangeRecHelper(coins, amount, currAmount - currCoin, currNumCoins + 1, coinQtyCopy);
            if (numCoinsTmp != -1) {
                minCoins = Math.min(minCoins, numCoinsTmp);
            }
        }

        if (minCoins == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            minCoins = -1;
        }

        return minCoins;
    }

    public Map<Integer, Integer> getMemo() {
        return memo;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Solution s = new Solution();
        System.out.println(s.coinChange(new int[]{1,2,5}, 11) + " coins used: ");

        for(int coin : s.getMemo().keySet()) {
            System.out.println( s.getMemo().get(coin)+ " of " + coin);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The return-value of `coinChangeRecHelper` depends on three of its arguments (`coins`, `currAmount`, and `currNumCoins`), but the `memo` cache is keyed by only one of those values (`currAmount`), which inherently means that it can't accurately cache the return-value. In other words, the code implicitly assumes that `coinChangeRecHelper(coins1, amount1, currAmount, currNumCoins1) == coinChangeRecHelper(coins2, amount2, currAmount, currNumCoins2)`, but that's a bad assumption.

> I was also able to get a memoized version to work by not passing in the `currNumCoins` as an argument to the recursive calls.

Yes, that approach would mostly fix this issue, by eliminating a mismatched parameter that the caching doesn't account for.

The only remaining issue is `coins`; if your `coinChange` method is called twice with different sets of coins, it will erroneously retain the old cache even though it's not applicable to the new call. To fix that, I'd recommend having `coinChange` create the cache and pass it as an argument to `coinChangeRecHelper`, rather than using an instance variable.